# check ul having li with specific class, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check ul or li elements whether have specific class every 5 seconds as folllows, but i am not getting result.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var a = $('ul li .current_page_item a').text();
  alert(a);
}, 5000);
```

how to do it ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between class selector and li otherwise, it may search for element with that class  inside `li`.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var a = $('ul li.current_page_item a').text();
  // -------------^-------- here
  alert(a);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: @VishalBorade : glad to help